# Titanium HealthKit Module - Cant create StatisticsQuery with Cumulative & Separate by source

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, healthkit

Im trying to create a Ti.Healthkit.StatisticsCollection where I can fetch number of steps taken, grouped per day. The thing is that I also need all sources, so I can filter ("manually") all steps added through Apple Health (manually) and other sources than the device and apple watch.

So; I've set up the Statistics query, everything looks fine. I can fetch all sources for each date. BUT, here's the thing, I can't no matter what, get the number of steps taken, per source.

```
    var query = HealthKit.createStatisticsCollectionQuery(
    {
        type        : HealthKit.OBJECT_TYPE_STEP_COUNT,
        filter      : HealthKit.createFilterForSamples(
        {
            startDate   : date_from,
            endDate     : date_to
        }),
        options     : HealthKit.STATISTICS_OPTION_CUMULATIVE_SUM | HealthKit.STATISTICS_OPTION_SEPARATE_BY_SOURCE,
        anchorDate  : anchorDate,
        interval    : 3600*24, // 24 hours
        onInitialResults    : function(e) 
        {
            if (e.errorCode !== undefined) 
            {
                //Utils.showError(e);
            } 
            else 
            {
                for(var i in e.statisticsCollection.statistics)
                {
                    var statistics = e.statisticsCollection.statistics[i];
                    console.log(statistics.sources[0]);
                    var quantity = statistics.getSumQuantityForSource(statistics.sources[0]);


                    var stepCount = quantity.valueForUnit(HealthKit.createUnit('count'));

                    console.log(statistics.sources);
                    //console.log(statistics.startDate);
                    console.log(stepCount);

                    for(var k in statistics.sources)
                    {
                        var _source = statistics.sources[k];


                        var quantity = statistics.getSumQuantity(_source);

                        console.log(_source);
                        console.log(quantity);
```

I have tried to follow the Apple docs as well as the Ti.HealthKit docs, and as far as I can see I've tried everything now. I've also tried to fetch the steps while I iterate all sources, to put it inside the statistics method;

sumQuantityForSource(_source)

but that only returns "null".

I can get the number of steps for a day, but it contains all sources steps..

Does anyone have any suggestion what to try? I feel like I've tried everything possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well okey, I worked with this for 5 hours and 10 min after this post I found out what I did wrong. I should have checked if "quantity" was null (var quantity = statistics.getSumQuantity(_source);) and just continue to the next iteration, because down the results array, i hit sources with steps..